# Binary search of a sorted array error

Tags: c#

```
using System.IO;
using System;
class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[10] { 1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8,10,9};
        int l = 1, r = 10, m = 0,t;

        sort(arr, 10); 
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please entert the number");
        t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        m = (l + r) / 2;

        while(l>=r)
        {
            if (arr[m] == t)
               Console.WriteLine("value is : " + m);
            if (arr[m] < t)
                l = m + 1;
            if (arr[m] > t)
                r = m - 1;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Target was found at index  " + arr[m]);
        }
    }

    static void sort(int[] dataset, int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = n - 1; j > i; j--)
                if (dataset[j] < dataset[j - 1])
                {
                    int temp = dataset[j];
                    dataset[j] = dataset[j - 1];
                    dataset[j - 1] = temp;
                }
    }
}
```

I tried running this program. I got output as :

> sh-4.3$ mcs *.cs -out:main.exe
>   sh-4.3$ mono main.exe
>   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
>   10
>   Please enter the number
>   5
>   sh-4.3$

What should I do to get the output of binary search from the sorted array?

Comment: You know you could use `Array.Sort` instead of writing your own bubble sort implementation.

Comment: You do realize that `l` is never >= `r`.  So you never enter the `while` loop.  I think you want `while(l<=r)`

Comment: thanks for the info @juharr. but i wanted to try it with bubble sort. is there an error in my code?

Comment: Also your `else` in the `while` loop will never be reached since `arr[m]` can only be equal to, less than, or greater than `t`.  There are no other possibilities.

Comment: Also you need to recalculate the `m` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issues with your code

1. Bad formatting - make it difficult to read
2. Bad variable names  - make it difficult to understand
3. Variables not declared close to where they are being used
4. Not using inbuilt routine for sort (assuming your focus is on learning binary search)

Now, logically the code fails, since the while loop for your binary search is flawed. Below is the correct code for your main - I have tried to keep it as similar to your code as possible, so you can understand the issues

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[10] { 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 9 };


    sort(arr, 10);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Console.Write(arr[i] + "\t");
    }

    int t;
    Console.WriteLine("Please entert the number");
    t = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    bool found = false;
    int l = 0, r = arr.Length - 1, m = 0;
    while (!found && l <= r) {
        m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (arr[m] == t)
            found = true;
        else if (arr[m] < t)
            l = m + 1;
        else if (arr[m] > t)
            r = m - 1;
    }
    if (found)
        Console.WriteLine($"value {t} is located at index {m}");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"value {t} not found");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your effort and help. i am a fresher in C# and in learning process... Sorry for the trouble..... Thanks again!

Comment: btw. 
Console.WriteLine($"value {t} is located at index {m}");

What is the necessity of $ and {} in that statement?

Comment: It is a new syntax with c# 6. In older versions, you can write that as `Console.WriteLine("value {0} is located at index {1}", t, m)`. Read up on [Interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) for more details